# Working in Mozilla but not working under IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs, flotr

I am using FLotr API to draw charts , and Flotr API is internally using Prototype.js . 
My Charts are working fine under Mozilla , but if i run charts in IE , its giving me Script Errors .

There is a function inside the Prototype.js file

```
 function observe(element, eventName, handler) {

    element = $(element);

alert(element);

}
```

When i put the alert for the element and run with Mozilla it displays as

1. [object Window]
2. [object HTMLDocument]
3. [object HTMLCanvasElement]
4. [object HTMLCanvasElement]
5. [object HTMLCanvasElement]**

But when i run with IE7 it displays

1. [Object]
2. [Object]
3. A run time error
4. object

Comment: Which IE version? The older versions don't support the `canvas` element afaik... but a look at the website (http://solutoire.com/flotr/) You have to include the Excanvas script that comes with Flotr.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 7 [does not support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element#Support) the `<canvas>` element. Thus, the runtime error.

You can use a [plug-in](http://arstechnica.com/software/news/2008/08/mozilla-drags-ie-into-the-future-with-canvas-element-plugin.ars) to add support for that element, though.

Answer (score 0):

try to include excanvas into your script tags:

http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much , i am using IE7 and i am already including Excanvas . but still the error remians the same .